# "Could not found module 'react-leaflet' "

Tags: react-native, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react leaflet in React Native. It was working fine in older versions of expo and react native. But I had to update my packages due to some reason. Now I'm getting the error "could not found module 'react-leaflet' ". Is there any way to resolve it without removing this package ?

I was on the expo sdk 44. It was working absolutely fine. But I had to update expo sdk to 50 because I was not getting notifications on device due older version of expo. Now I'm getting notifications on my device but It's giving me error of react-leaflet. I'm not able to run my app now. I know react-leaflet is made for web applications and is not recommended to use it in React Native. But is there any way to remove this error without removing this package ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pIze.png)

Image shows the exact error I'm getting